# targeting multiple selectors in a container for new different styles

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's think we have a couple of elements (`p`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `label`) that are contained in `div.container`. All element has been styled outside the container

```
p, h4, h5, h6, label{color: #fff;}
```

but we want to set new style for them when are contained in that special container so i usually write:

```
div.container p, div.container h4, 
div.container h5, div.container h6, 
div.container label{color: #ddd;}
```

everything is OK, just this is too long too coding. is there a way (shorter coding) to targeting all those elements? like:

```
div.container [p, h4, h5, h6, label] {color: #ddd;}
```

**note:** i don't want to use pre-processors.

Comment: interesting !! looking forward for the answer, as recently I had half of page this way.

Comment: Stylesheet languages could be the answer, but I am new to that.

Comment: There is nothing like that what you are expecting. But, i think it will be possible with Sass, Compass & other pre-processors

Comment: @SVS don't want to use pre-processors

Comment: Are my two variants of solution not satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no absolute way to do that without pre-processors.

Answer (score 0):

Not in plain CSS, but in SCSS ([Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)):

```
div.container {
  p, h4, h5, h6, label {color: #ddd;}
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/rq7hx/

Comment: don't want to use pre-processors

Answer (score -1):

Without more information about your markup this is only what can i say:

You can drop out tag selector (it is unnecessary.):

```
.container p,
.container h4, 
.container h5,
.container h6, 
.container label {
    color: #ddd;
}
```

**On the other side**, you can use cascade principle of CSS and add for all `p`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6` and `label` identically classes (say `.example`) and then you can stack you CSS like this:

```
.example { color: #fff; }
.container .example { color: #ddd; }
```