# style different divs or selectors within a container with different styles

Tags: css

Still coming to terms with inline CSS and wondering if this is really easy or I'm over-thinking things.

Is it possible to style different divs or selectors within a container with different styles

For example. I have several divs [A,B,C & D] within a container that require an a:link to be red and divs E & F within the same container to be styled differently as say, blue. Can it be achieved with something like this:

```
}.main-content-divA a:link, .main-content-divB a:link, .main-content-divC a:link, .main-content-divD a:link,{
color: #ff0000;
text-decoration: none;}

}.main-content-divE a:link, .main-content-divF a,{
color: #00ffff;
text-decoration: none;}
```

Is "pre-processors" [targeting multiple selectors in a container for new different styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009519/targeting-multiple-selectors-in-a-container-for-new-different-styles) the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="typeA">
      <a href="#">red Links</a>
  </div>
  <div class="typeB">
      <a href="#">red Links</a>
  </div>
  <div class="typeC">
      <a href="#">red Links</a>
  </div>
  <div class="typeD">
      <a href="#">red Links</a>
  </div>
  <div class="typeE">
      <a href="#">blue links</a>
  </div>
  <div class="typeF">
      <a href="#">blue links</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper a {
  color: red;
}
#wrapper .typeE a, #wrapper .typeF a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: While all the other answers are sufficient, this models your behavior the best through the use of overriding inheritted properties.

Comment: I think this very well maybe what I was after. Cheers

Comment: Be sure to accept it if it solved your problem! :) Otherwise, comment so me and others can help you

Comment: Solved! Thanks ProfileTwist and others.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you can't just use classes?

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="typeA">
        <a href="#">Should be #ff0000</a>
    </div>
    <div class="typeA">
        <a href="#">Should be #ff0000</a>
    </div>
    <div class="typeB">
        <a href="#">Should be #0000ff</a>
    </div>
    <div class="typeB">
        <a href="#">Should be #0000ff</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#container .typeA a:link {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container .typeB a:link {
    color: #00ffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was trying to keep the CSS short with a 'catch-all' style for the a link. I'm sure I've seen it but then I'm probably confusing it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of interesting selectors, maybe this would help:
[Tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)

I think you would want something like: X:nth-child(n) (it is nr. 22 in that list).
Or very similar.

Hope this helps, GL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main-content">
    <a href="">My Link</a>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <a href="">My Link</a>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <a href="" class="blue">My Link</a>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <a href="" class="blue">My Link</a>
</div>

.main-content a{
   color:#ff0000;
   text-decoration:none;
}
.main-content a.blue{
    color:#00ffff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, along with Joe's input I should have the answer.